# Android Studio guest hasn't come online in 7 seconds

Tags: android-studio

When I first start the emulator in Android Studio I get an information message,

> guest hasn't come online in 7 seconds retrying

I am curious as to how to stop this because while it is on my screen for about 40 seconds I cannot do anything in the emulator.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I had the same problem. Selecting Cold Boot Now in AVD manager solves the problem.

But I have to open AVD manager each time when I want to launch Emulator and I just want to click on Run app button and select device, without opening AVD manager.

To solve this: open AVD manager -> Edit device -> Show Advanced Settings -> Boot option -> select Cold Boot instead of Quick boot.

Comment: I cannot see the Boot options. Currently using Android Studio 3.1.2. :/

Comment: @b-fg Strange. I have checked in my AS, Boot options is available.

Comment: Weird. I might need to reinstall.

Comment: @b-fg Which Android Emulator you use ?

Comment: The one in Android Studio. I can run cold boot as @Boris answer but not configure it on a new virtual device. Nevermind.

Answer (score 100):

Actually 'Cold Boot Now' may work in this situation [image: avd manager with emulator action menu showing Cold Boot Now option]

Comment: How do you do this via the `.ini` files in your `~/.android/avd` directory?

Comment: Use `emulator @_avd_name_ -no-snapshot-load` to perform a cold boot from the command line.

Comment: Works only if done each time. If cold boot option is not selected each time problem remains.

Comment: that sounds like a fix but I don't really see how to explain this.

Comment: I am getting this warning(or error) while running the emulator via command... is there any flag for cold boot?

Answer (score 14):

tools->Android->AVD Manager

Choose the device then Cold Boot Now

Answer (score 7):

maybe it's bug from intel haxm 6.2.1, because after i update i got same problem.

I solved by recreate emulator and testing again

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve this issue by updating the `.ini` file manually. (I was not able to find a corresponding setting in the GUI.)

The location of the `.ini` file, relative to your home directory, is:

```
~/.android/avd/MyDevice.avd/config.ini
```

where `MyDevice` refers to the configured device name.

Depending on your operating system, you may find your home directory according [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory#Default_home_directory_per_operating_system).

Change the entry within `config.ini` from `no` to `yes`:

```
fastboot.forceColdBoot=yes
```

Answer (score 2):

1. I specified AVD memory 2048 Mbyte instead of 1536 Mbyte. Things
   started to work again. (I'm developing on macbook.)
2. I tried "Kuldeep Chandel" solution which is to duplicate AVD and my app runs again too. Because of that I specified RAM again as 1536
   Mbyte. Guess what... It worked...

I think AVD confuses to handle things and we need to duplicate the current AVD, and use it instead of the problematic one.

Answer (score 1):

In "Your Virual Device" - Click on Duplicate OR Duplicate your Device. It will work like Charm.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue on using Android API 28 emulator with Android Studio 3.0.1. Android API 28 requires Studio 3.1 and above. Once I updated Studio to 3.1.4 and Android Emulator to the latest version, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Seting default settings for problem device from Android Device Manager resolved issue for me.