# Flutter - Emulator is not starting when attempting to run Flutter app

Tags: android-studio, flutter

When developing an android app, I was able to configure a 'deployment target' to be a particular emulator.
I was able to do the same yesterday, but I don't know what happened because now there is 'no devices'

[image]

I've tried starting up a compatible emulator first instead, but the emulator seems to freeze up and I get the error message, 'No device connected...' when I try to then run the Flutter app.

[image]

I thought I didn't have to start an emulator yesterday.
Is there something missing in the 'Edit Configuration' screen above?

I could just select the device from the dropdown.
Regardless, the emulator isn't working at all now.  What's this message, 'Guest isn't online after 7 seconds'
Would that have something to do with this?

Answer (score 3):

*UPDATE*  Selected 'Wipe Data' and the emulators don't freeze up in 'black screen'

Googled til I find this approach.

Comment: That does not always work for me.
I also get the same error when oustide of Android studio trying to run the emulator through Cordova. Strange that nothing else is to be found about this error through Google. Everything I get seems to be in Chinese or other Asian languages.

Comment: Oh, here is another question asking the same, with some more thorough answers, it seems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48010244/android-studio-guest-hasnt-come-online-in-7-seconds